# Error - ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows

Tags: plsql

I am trying execute the below procedure but keep getting the below:

**CODE:**

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
  aID VARCHAR2(4):= '&AuthID';
  aName BK_AUTHOR.FNAME%TYPE;
  aSurname BK_AUTHOR.LNAME%TYPE;
  bTit BK_BOOKS.TITLE%TYPE;
  bCat BK_BOOKS.CATEGORY%TYPE;
  bPrice BK_COSTS.COST%TYPE;

BEGIN
 book_info(aID,aName,aSurname,bTit,bCat,bPrice);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(aName||'-'||aSurname||'wrote the book ('||bTit||') that is in category '||bCat||' and it cost R'||TO_CHAR(bPrice,'99999.99'));
END;
/
```

**ERROR**

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
ORA-06512: at "SYS.BOOK_INFO", line 13
ORA-06512: at line 9
```

Adding code from comment:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE book_info(
    AuthID IN OUT VARCHAR2,
    Name OUT BK_AUTHOR.FNAME%TYPE,
    Surname OUT BK_AUTHOR.LNAME%TYPE,
    Tit OUT BK_BOOKS.TITLE%TYPE,
    Cat OUT BK_BOOKS.CATEGORY%TYPE,
    Price OUT BK_COSTS.COST%TYPE )
IS
BEGIN
  SELECT FNAME,
    LNAME,
    TITLE,
    CATEGORY,
    COST
  INTO Name,
    Surname,
    Tit,
    Cat,
    Price
  FROM BK_BOOKS,
    BK_AUTHOR,
    BK_COSTS
  WHERE BK_COSTS.ISBN   = BK_BOOKS.ISBN
  AND BK_BOOKS.AUTHORID = AuthID;
END book_info;
/
```

Comment: What does the function book_info look like? And are you writing these procedures in SYS schema by any chance?

Comment: You need to post the code to book_info. You are probably doing a select...into and the select is returning more than 1 row.

Comment: Here is the Procedure:

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE book_info
(
    AuthID IN OUT varchar2,
    Name OUT BK_AUTHOR.FNAME%TYPE,
    Surname OUT BK_AUTHOR.LNAME%TYPE,
    Tit OUT BK_BOOKS.TITLE%TYPE,
    Cat OUT BK_BOOKS.CATEGORY%TYPE,
    Price OUT BK_COSTS.COST%TYPE
)
IS
BEGIN

    SELECT FNAME, LNAME, TITLE, CATEGORY, COST
    INTO Name, Surname, Tit, Cat, Price
    FROM BK_BOOKS, BK_AUTHOR, BK_COSTS
    WHERE BK_COSTS.ISBN = BK_BOOKS.ISBN
    AND BK_BOOKS.AUTHORID = AuthID;
END book_info;
/

Comment: Please edit the question and put this function there with the appropriate code formatting.

Comment: Also post your basic table structures. Your SQL needs joins between bk_books, bk_author, and bk_costs. The only way to avoid your error is to return only one row, so you need to join appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be due to multiple reasons looking at the code of book_info.

First of all - There is a cross join between bk_books and bk_author. You need to add the join condition between these two tables, something like -

```
WHERE BK_COSTS.ISBN = BK_BOOKS.ISBN AND bk_books.authorid = bk_author.authorid AND AND BK_BOOKS.AUTHORID = AuthID
```

You should also check for duplicates in the resultant join of these tables based on Authorid.

**Edit**: Forgot to mention, please don't use the SYS user for any development related activities like creating procedures or functions. From the error message, it seems like book_info procedure is inside SYS user. You should never log into this user unless you are a DBA and using it for sysdba related activities.